# Jquery - easyui datagrid couldn't display the data in the Google browser, but you can display the data in the firefox browser

Tags: jquery-easyui

I'm using jquery - easyui datatgrid while on a demo Only when using firefox demo shows data using any other browser won't display the data

Comment: Can you share some code samples?

Comment: Sometimes you've got a bad code, that is tolerated, bypassed or auto-fixed in one webbrower but not in another. Without code, it is not possible to give you anything better than this.